# Slow image draw with Chrome only

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This is a basic text input that adds an avatar image and text into a chat-like box `div`, the avatar can be any number of hundreds, so I can't just make it a class.

Problem: Using standard `<img>` via html insertion gets slow redraw of image in Chrome.
IE and Firefox instantly display the image (after caching the first entry).

I've timed the main function itself and it finishes in 6ms or so (great), however at that stage Chrome has rendered the text and not even started to render the image.
Tested on another faster computer - no change.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisadmin/yw24h2aj/

html:

```
<div id="newMsg" style="border:1px solid black"></div>
<br/>Type some stuff and hit enter<br/>
<input class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br" maxlength="400" type="text" id="outgoing" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) displayMsg()" />
```

js:

```
ngcClientTag = 0;
opt_avatar = '1';

function displayMsg() {
    var message = $('#outgoing').val();
    $('#outgoing').val('');
    ngcClientTag++;
    var innerHtml =
        '<div id="c_m_' + (ngcClientTag - 1) + '" class="msg1">' +
        '<div style="float:left">' +
        '<img class="msg2" src="http://parkbenchgames.com/images/ava/' + opt_avatar + '.png"/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div>' +
        '<div class="msg3" id="s_m_' + (ngcClientTag - 1) + '">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div style="clear:both">' + '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    $("#newMsg").append(innerHtml);
    $("#s_m_" + (ngcClientTag - 1)).text(message);
}
```

css:

```
.msg1 {
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
.msg2 {
    position:relative;
    margin-right:5px;
    border:none;
    height:25px;
    width:46px;
}
.msg2a {
    position:relative;
    margin-right:5px;
    border:none;
    height:25px;
    width:3px;
}
.msg3 {
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: You are on to something, however in your fiddle. if you type a single letter like A and hit enter, it will load quick up to 15 times, then go slow. If you type 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' after the forth or fifth line it will load slow again, even if the next line is 'A'. once it goes slow, it wont come back :-(

Comment: ill check that out tomorrow.  comment on the answer instead of the question next time so I get a notification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is so annoying! I have had the exact same issue: dynamically created images do not flicker in FF, but they flicker in Chrome.

I don't have any reference work for the internals of Chrome saying *why* it happens, but here is how I solved it when it happened to me. 2 things:

**1. Don't use `img src`.**

Load the image as a background image to a div. Chrome must load/cache those differently...?

**2. Preload the image.**

That makes all the difference. In FF you can achieve a preload by creating a DOM element containing the image, ala

```
var $img=$('<img>');
$img.attr('src','image.ext');
```

However, Chrome requires that you actually append the image to the DOM (somewhere off screen) if you want to preload it, something like

```
var $img=$('<img>');
$img.attr('src','image.ext');
$img.css({position:'absolute',top:'-10000px',left:'-10000px'});
$('body').append($img);
```

Since you already have the `displayMsg()` function ready to go, you can preload the image by calling it with an empty `message` and then immediately removing the element it creates so it doesn't clutter the screen.

The html/css were unchanged.

**JS**

```
ngcClientTag = 0;
opt_avatar = '1';

/* PRELOAD *///===========================
//you know the avatar number, grab the image
var img='http://parkbenchgames.com/images/ava/' + opt_avatar + '.png';
//make it a background style instead of an img tag
var bgStyle="background-image:url("+img+")";
$(document).ready(function () {
//preload the image!
displayMsg();
//use setTimeout to make sure we are on the next iteration of event loop
setTimeout(function() {$('.msg1').remove()},0);
});


function displayMsg() {
    var message = $('#outgoing').val();
    $('#outgoing').val('');
    ngcClientTag++;
    var innerHtml =
        '<div id="c_m_' + ngcClientTag + '" class="msg1">';
                 //display img in div instead of img tag
                 //borrow class msg2 to give it the same dimensions as the img
    innerHtml +='<div style="float:left;'+bgStyle+'" class="msg2">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div>' +
        '<div class="msg3" id="s_m_' + ngcClientTag + '">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div style="clear:both">' + '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    $("#newMsg").append(innerHtml);
    $("#s_m_" + ngcClientTag).text(message); // for text safe insert
}
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/yo307pt7/4/

Comment: Oh, sorry about that - will do

Comment: @user975033 I tried playing with it, but the cases where it happens (wait 15 times, type lots of letters, etc.) are not specific enough to address and / or reliably reproduce the flicker under the same conditions. Sometimes it would flicker, sometimes it wouldn't. That said, I'm not looking into this any further. I think the current approach covers most situations

Comment: I think my computer must be slower, its a slow redraw rather than a flicker, but thanks for your efforts, After some research I found it is probably a Chrome v40 problem. Your answer will help others in the future however.

Comment: just for Chrome v40? Yeesh. Does not suprise me, that browser is all about doing funky optimizations for speed, naturally that would backfire and make something redraw slower than FF! Hope any of that code helped you out a little!

Comment: Well not confirmed, but certainly the Chrome of 6 months ago was drawing at the usual speed of browsers. From what I read recently Chrome 40 seems to be having some issues and is using some kind of different engine at some level.

Comment: Yes it's an interesting way to do it, and I'll will keep it in my repertoire, cheers bro

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a complete FUBAR: I had (at some prehistoric stage) used PHP to force the browser to pick up the new images via no-cache options.
A VERY BAD IDEA.

Chrome followed a more ruthless policy than other browsers.

The point of my answer is, use a '?number_here' at the end of the image url, as a broad js policy, will give perfect updates without compromising speed.

Change the 'number_here' when u wish for a perfect update on browser refresh.
Use a variable to be smart.

```
pv = '?24';
...
output = '<img src="\images\icon20.png"'+pv+'>';
...
```